# How can I make a SeekBar take up the width available between a TextView and an ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'd like the TextView and ImageButton to take up space based on their size & have the SeekBar take up whatever space remains. Here's my current code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/seekbar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ccBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_captions_off"
            app:tint="@color/white" />


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

With this code, the SeekBar has no width & the ccBtn appears in the center of the screen. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Ricardo's answer, the code will be

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ccBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_captions_off"
        app:tint="@color/white" />


</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Image preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGrEo.png

In the image I've centered it a bit, which can be achieved with gravity center and no bottom margin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `weight` property,
setting SeekBar `weight` to 1 and `layout_width` to `0dp` should do it.

also, on a side note, try to be consistent when naming your variables, don't `do_this` for one variable `andThis` for another

Comment: Thanks for the side note. I agree, consistency is important.